# jaxrs variable @Path

Tags: java, jax-rs

I have a method annotated with jax-rs like this

```
@POST
@Path("/somepath")
public Response testPost(...)
```

I would like to use instead of "/somepath" a java string constant (retrieved from configuration). Is that possible?

I know that I can do @Path({somepath})
and then use @PathParam to replace it but that's a different use case where the caller passes a dynamic param.

Answer (score 2):

In java, annotation parameters must be compile-time constants.
Thus, you will not be able to use configuration retrieved values in the @Path annotation.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way without annotations?

Comment: @user35202 with Jersey, you can build your resource models programmatically, but there is no standard JAX-RS way.